# golang returning from cache

Tags: postgresql, go, caching

My response time is about **3** second, so I want to decrease the response time. The first thing that I think is returning from cache but I couldn't find any framework or explanation about that. How can I achieve it or is there any alternative solution?

Should I use this framework:
https://github.com/mediocregopher/radix.v2

I am using `postgresql` for db and in for loop I call this code:

```
err := GetDB().Table("table_name").Find(&words).Error
```

Comment: Are you reconnecting for each response? If that's what you do,  it'll take time. What is the GetDB() function? You seem to be using some sort of framework to access the db already, what is that?

Comment: @BurakSerdar I am not reconnectting DB every request. I have already connected the DB in base.go class and i am getting istance of it

Comment: In that case, if the resultset is large or if you're running an involved query, it may take time, though the db should provide some caching of that already. It is difficult to guess why it is taking so long. I suggest you figure out the bottleneck first before trying caching tools. For instance: does it take 3 seconds when you run it with another client (pgAdmin)?

Comment: i think this problems occurres cause in the table there is over 25k record. So in for loop i try to get data from table(for 20 time minimum). Do you have any idea how can i use effective way for it @BurakSerdar

Comment: Are you trying to load 25K rows? If you need to do this once, you can simply run it once and cache the result, you don't need a separate framework for that. If you need to load these rows often because they are changing, then the solution depends on the exact use case and how those rows are changing. Maybe you can add a version mark to the rows and retrieve only the ones modified since you read them?

Comment: how can i cache the result. should i keep it in global variable?(as i mentioned on question i am newbie on golang and db) @BurakSerdar

Comment: Yes, you can keep it in a global variable. Initialize on program startup, and use throughout the program.

Comment: Okay i will try

Comment: @BurakSerdar ok its returning about 20 millisecond now. Thank you. If you write this as answer then i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too broad but based on the discussion above, I believe what you're trying to do is to load some sort of static data from a database that will be used in your program, and it does not need to be refreshed. In that case, it makes sense to load the data when you connect the database once and keep it in a global variable under a package. For instance:

```
package model

var SomeData []SomeType
```

```
package main

func main() {
  // Load data from the db
  model.SomeData = loadedData
  // Start the program...  
}
```

This assumes `model.SomeData` will not change during the program. If you need to, for instance, reload it periodically, a better structure for the program is:

```
package model

var someData []SomeType
var someDataLock sync.RWMutex

func GetData() []SomeType {
   someDataLock.RLock()
   defer someDataLock.RUnlock()
   return someData
}

func SetData(in []SomeType) {
   someDataLock.Lock()
   defer someDataLock.Unlock()
   someData=in
}
```

Then you use `model.SetData` to set the data, and `model.GetData` to get the data in a thread-safe manner.